# Import-Csv with regex

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I want to import a CSV and filter out the data with certain regex's. Example of input CSV:

```
John;Doe;18
Peter;Test;21
```

I want to filter out individual names, for example: I only want to see the persons with the lastname starting with a 'd' and those who are 20 years and above.

How can I write the filtered data into a new array? Here's the piece of code I've written so far:

```
$persons = import-csv -Header "surname", "lastname", "age" -delimiter ";" data.csv
$persons | ForEach-Object {
if $_.lastname -match "^d" {
    #?
}
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$persons = Import-Csv -Header "surname", "lastname", "age" -Delimiter ";" data.csv | where { 
    $_.lastname -match '^d' -and $_.age -ge 20
}
```

It filters out the records with lastname starting with "d" and have an age of 20 or greater. Finally, it saves the results in an array called `$persons`

Answer (score 0):

```
$persons | Where-Object {$_.LastName -like "d*" -and $_.Age -gt 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression

```
^([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)$
```

Tried it with perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

while (<>) {

    if ( /^([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)$/ ){
        print "first =". $1 . "\n";
        print "last  =". $2 . "\n";
        print "age   =". $3 . "\n";
    }
}
```

which gives this output

```
first =John
last  =Doe
age   =18

first =Peter
last  =Test
age   =21
```

however focus on the regular expression